# Breaking up a web-link and using for loop in Python

Tags: python, email, web-crawler

I am writing a python script for crawling emails

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://stuactonline.tamu.edu/app/organization/profile/public/id/1488')

doc = driver.page_source

emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',doc)

print(emails)
```

if you notice the end of the link is the number 1488. I am trying to break it up where I can have a for loop that loops from 50 to about 5000 because there are multiple emails I want to get from the different websites ended in numbers from 1000 to 5000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily parametrize the url:

```
for i in range(1000, 5000):
    driver.get('https://stuactonline.tamu.edu/app/organization/profile/public/id/' + str(i))

    #Your stuff...
```

Comment: do you know a way I can avoid repetition, some emails are being repeated and i dont want that

Comment: You can do something like `emails = list(set(emails))`.

Comment: thanks it worked. What exactly does `list()` and `set()` do in this case tho

Comment: `set()` converts the input list to a Python [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) which has no duplicates by construction. `list()` is needed to convert the result back to a list and depending on the use case may not be mandatory.